# Enabling Java in Chrome on 32 bit 14.10

Tags: java, google-chrome, runescape

I am trying to run Runescape in Chrome (it has game.ws in its file address http://www.runescape.com/game.ws), and while I can run this game in Firefox I can't seem to run it in Chrome. To overcome this I downloaded `jre-8u31-linux-i586.tar.gz` from http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=101398 and ran (based on https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml):

```
sudo -s
mv /home/fusion809/Downloads/jre-8u31-linux-i586.tar.gz /usr/java/
cd /usr/java/
tar zxvf jre-8u31-linux-i586.tar.gz
ln -s /usr/java/jre1.8.0_31/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so /opt/google/chrome
```

(where `/opt/google/chrome` are where all the plugin files listed at about:plugins are)

I then closed Chrome and relaunched it and opened runescape up and it didn't load. I know of Oracle Java that you can get in the Software centre and it is installed on my PC but this was the only way of installing Java such that Chrome could read it that I could find a guide for online.

Answer (score 0):

[Java is no longer supported by Google Chrome](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml) as of chrome version 42. Some versions below 42 also did not include Java. See [This](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml) for more information. Chrome stopped including all NPAPI plugins in version 45.